# Can I set run priority of a php script in CLI mode thru setting in ini file or directly from script?

Tags: windows, php

I mean settings that can be changed from task manager like "realtime" or "idle".
My script is taking a lot of resources and cripples GUI programs that are running simultaneously.

I want to set it's priority to idle from script. I do not need it to be 100% fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Windows command line, you have several options:

```
start /b /low program.exe
start /b /high program.exe
start /b /realtime program.exe
start /b /normal program.exe
start /b /abovenormal program.exe
start /b /belownormal program.exe
```

Comment: Well I made a separate runphp.bat file and pointed all *.php files to run thru this file when clicked with a mouse, so there would be no surprise if a script is heavy for the CPU or memory. content of this file is simple: start /b /belownormal php.exe %1
@echo off
pause>nul

Answer (score 1):

The answer offered by @stillstanding is totally valid. I just wanted to add some details from my own experiments.

If your script is using 50% of the CPU, adding `/low` it won't make it consume less. The only difference is when another process with a higher scheduling priority comes along and needs CPU. When the CPU usage reaches 99-100%, your PHP CLI script will be throttled back.

To put it with other words, you need to schedule a higher priority for processes that need it, so that the machine is still responsive.

Adding `start` to commands what were run directly with `exec()`, may raise a problem when using paths and parameters. Also I had the issue that the processes started were stuck at 0% CPU usage.

Here is a working example:

```
$cmd = 'start /b /low /d "C:\php\" php.exe -f ""C:\Data\www\script.php" foo="1" bar="text"';
pclose(popen($command, "r"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Natively, in PHP, there is the pcntl_setpriority() function. However, that's Unix-only.

For Windows; this command line program lets you change the priority of already-running processes:
http://gilchrist.ca/jeff/SetPriority/index.html

You could do an exec() in your PHP script to call this program perhaps.